# Does quantum mechanics violate the law of conservation of energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, electrons, energy-conservation, superposition

I recently learned that an electron can exist in two places at the same time simultaneously, which was pretty intriguing to understand.
But to me there is seemingly a flaw in this fact.

The charge of single electron is $1.6021\times 10^{-19}$ coulombs. According to above fact if a single electron can exist in two places simultaneously this should collectively mean that there is charge of $2\times 1.6021\times 10^{-19}$ coulomb arising from a single electron at two discrete places and this seemingly violates the law of conservation of energy, as energy seemed to be doubled from a single electron. Is this really the case?

Comment: OP, quantum mechanics doesn’t violate energy conservation

Comment: The body of the question is about charge, not energy, conservation, which also is not violated by QM.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> a electron can exist at two places in the same time simultaneously

This is not quite correct. At no time is an electron ever definitely in two locations. An electron’s position is uncertain, and until it is measured it is indefinite. When it is measured it has only a single location.

Regarding energy, that is really a separate question. By Noether’s theorem we know that energy is conserved because the laws of physics are the same today as they were yesterday. That is irrespective of the other details of those laws.